# React Native Firebase Display Two Collections in One Component (JOIN Query required)

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

{Solved, below comment solved it for me!}
[ Seeing links of images posted below makes this question easy to understand! ]
I would like to display in a component called post two different collections attributes. I have a component called post where I display different attributes of documens inside collection posts, but in that same component I would also like to show attribute from another collection called users, those two collections are connected with collection posts having atrribute userHandle which has a value same as some certain id of some user. I will show it all in pictures. In my firebase I have a collection called posts and I call it here; first in my Fire.js i do

```
export async function getPosts(PostsRetreived) {
  var post = [];

  var snapshot = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("posts")
    .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
    .get();

  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const PostItem = doc.data();
    PostItem.id = doc.id;
    post.push(PostItem);
  });
  //console.log(post + "here");
  PostsRetreived(post);
}
```

and then in my HomeScreen I do this;

```
onPostsReceived = (post) => {
    try {
      this.setState({ post: post });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      Alert.alert(
        "Posts failed to load, you need to check your internet connection."
      );
    }
  };
```

and this;

```
async componentDidMount() {
    getPosts(this.onPostsReceived);
}
```

inside collection posts each document has attributes text, timestamp and userHandle
and here I call different attributes of posts;

```
renderPost = (post) => {
    //console.log(post.text);
    return (
      <View style={styles.feedItem}>
        <Image
          source={
            //this.state.user.avatar
            // ? { uri: this.state.user.avatar }
            // :
            require("../assets/tempAvatar.jpg")
          }
          style={styles.avatar}
        />
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "space-between",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.name}>{}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.timestamp}>
                {moment(post.timestamp).toDate().toDateString()}
              </Text>
            </View>

            <Ionicons name="ios-more" size={24} color="#73788B" />
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.post}>{post.text}</Text>
          <Image
            source={post.image && { uri: post.image }}
            source={post.image}
            style={styles.postImage}
            resizeMode="cover"
          />
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="elephant"
              size={24}
              color="#ffa163"
              style={{ marginRight: 16 }}
              //onPress={() => this.xDD(this.state.comments)}
              //onPress={() => navigation.navigate("CommentsScreen")}
              //onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Comments")}
              onPress={() => this.renderComment}
            />
            <Ionicons
              name="ios-chatboxes"
              size={24}
              color="#73788B"
              onPress={() => this.postComment(post.id)}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

THE KEY THING I WANT IS WHERE HERE I HAVE IMAGE i want to put avatar aka profile picture of a coresponding user. avatar is an atribute of documents inside collection users. So which user wrote the post I want his avatar shown inside a post. for that i need to display content of two collections inside one component (a post). IN THE PICTURES I LINKED IT CAN BE EASILY SEEN how those two collections are connected via collection post having attribue userHandle and that equaling id of some user. HOW TO QUERY THIS? So that I have two collections like some kind of a JOIN. I Need code for this and not people saying like in other similar questions "remodel ur database" or "use 2 queries". I tried and idk how to do it pls help me. below is also an image of this component post and u can see where avatar pic would go. THANK YOU.

[enter image description here][1]
enter image description here
[enter image description here][2]
[enter image description here][3]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWOFc.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDkT4.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfIgL.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to re-think your approach.  Firestore is referred to as "NoSQL" for a reason - it isn't SQL.

(BTW, image links and posts are HIGHLY discouraged here on Stackoverflow - pasted the formatted text instead - you can't expect us to trust the security of your links)

As a suggestion, tho, remember that in NoSQL, DRY essentially does not apply - in your case, save the link to the avatar image in the same document as the post WHEN YOU SAVE THE POST - you'll likely already have the user data at that point.  This data is very very likely to be static - certainly for the life of the post document.  Costs you nothing, easy to access when you need it.

You really NEED to rethink your entire approach when using NoSQL - old SQL habits will *not* help you.

Comment: I understand its noSql but it can definetly be done. I need a smart query with sth like .where(userHandle==id) with both collections queried i can kinda imagine solution but don't have enough skills to pull it off. I have something similar working for my comments (they need to know to which post they belong and I did sth like join here successfully).

Comment: And btw about u saying about images I wanted to post normal ones stackoverflow doesn't let me cause they sąy I'm still new and these links are auto generated by them so can be trusted.

Comment: I'm not employed by Google on this, but trust me: cross-collection queries are SPECIFICALLY BY DESIGN not part of NoSQL - it's kinda the *definition* of NoSQL.  I know SQL strongly discourages putting the same information in more than one "table" - but NoSQL is *not* tables, and *encourages* putting static data wherever it needs to be to be efficient. Since a chat record is *created* by a user, adding the link to the user image is *trivial* at document creation time.

Comment: Continuing to ask for a "JOIN" in a NoSQL database is like asking for a 10-32 Pan Head Machine Screw in a pastry shop - you won't get it, and it isn't relevant.  If you insist you data be accessed like SQL, use SQL.  Firestore isn't SQL.

Comment: I absolutely and totally understand u. I know what noSql is versus SQL. I just think this can be done, just not with one query but two. And I said I need sth LIKE join, and not join itself. I believe this can be done and I hope somebody can answer. To show data from two collections in component doesn't sound undoable to me tbh. Than u for ur comments tho

Comment: Amusingly, in your original question you SPECIFICALLY REJECT two queries, and now you want someone to write the second query.  I show data from multiple collections/queries all the time - try writing the code, seeing errors and ask about the errors.  StackOverflow is not about showing you *how* to start - it's about help with *specific* problems.

Comment: As to fetching an image: I store user "avatar" images in Firestore Storage.  I use a *very* predicatible path - for example, the user "avatar" might be stored at path /users/{userID}/images/avatar.jpg.  So take the userID from the message (in the messages collection), comkbine it into a predictable path similar to what I just showed, and use the "create storage URL" function which COMPLETELY SYNCHRONOUSLY generates the URL.  Serve up the URL to the output, and the browser will fetch the image.

Comment: Your original comment helped me! Thank u it works! I simply did what u said, I saved the link to the avatar image in the same document as the post when i save the post. Thank u!